# How to store Unicode characters in Oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, character-encoding

I have an Oracle database. I tried to stored Arabic characters in a table, but it leads to reverse question marks in the database. The datatype of the column is VARCHAR2.

I used the following query to check the characterset.

```
SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS
```

The characterset is WE8MSWIN1252. How can I handle it?

```
SQL> select * from nls_database_parameters ORDER BY PARAMETER;

      PARAMETER                      VALUE
      ------------------------------ ---------------------------------------
      NLS_CALENDAR                   GREGORIAN
      NLS_CHARACTERSET               WE8MSWIN1252
      NLS_COMP                       BINARY
      NLS_CURRENCY                   $
      NLS_DATE_FORMAT                DD-MON-RR
      NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE              AMERICAN
      NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY              $
      NLS_ISO_CURRENCY               AMERICA
      NLS_LANGUAGE                   AMERICAN
      NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS           BYTE
      NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET         AL16UTF16

      PARAMETER                      VALUE
      ----------------------- ----------------------------------------
      NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP            FALSE
      NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS         .,
      NLS_RDBMS_VERSION              11.2.0.3.0
      NLS_SORT                       BINARY
      NLS_TERRITORY                  AMERICA
      NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT           DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
      NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT        DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
      NLS_TIME_FORMAT                HH.MI.SSXFF AM
      NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT             HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR

      20 rows selected.
```

Comment: Can you upgrade the database characterset? It would be to AL32UTF8.

Comment: @Ben without upgrade, can we fix this? I tried to change the column to nvarchar, its not working

Comment: Finally i upgraded the DB, its working fine. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do yourself (and all other people working on the database) a favor and upgrade your database to use AL32UTF8 as the default database character set. It's a bigger one time effort than using `NVARCHAR2` for a few selected columns but it saves a lot of work and trouble in the future.

See [Character Set Migration](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch11charsetmig.htm) for instructions.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot store arabic characters in the character set WE8MSWIN1252.

But there is an escape route: the [national character set](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch2charset.htm#NLSPG180).
If you define the column as [`NVARCHAR2`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#i45685) instead of `VARCHAR2`, any character can be stored in it.

Comment: I changed column to NVARCHAR2, using following query

Comment: ALTER TABLE DB_KEYWD
MODIFY KEY  NVARCHAR2(300);
commit; I tried to enter the arabic characters, but it stores reverse question marks

Comment: Hard to believe. What does [`DUMP`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions063.htm#SQLRF00635) say about the contents of the field? If things are still not clear, share the Java code you are using.

Comment: "insert into DB_KEYWD (KEY,VALUE) values(?,?),new int[]{Types.VARCHAR, Types.BIGINT}" this is how i am constructing query. If i change this to NVARCHAR, then i get exception as column data type doesnt match.

Comment: When i use that dump and check, i get the following result: Typ=96 Len=15 CharacterSet=WE8MSWIN1252: bf,bf,bf,bf,bf,bf,bf, ,bf,bf,bf,bf,bf,bf,bf

Comment: please find the above comments

Comment: That dump shows that this is *not* a field of type `NVARCHAR2`, but rather `CHAR`. You must have used the wrong field.

Comment: I changed the column to NVARCHAR2, Executed the dump command as below: SELECT DUMP(KEY) "OCTAL"  FROM MDB_KEYWD  WHERE KEY = 'heelo'                                                                                                Results are: Typ=1 Len=10: 0,104,0,101,0,101,0,108,0,111

Comment: That looks fine. Now try to store some Arabic into that field. It should work just fine.

Comment: I created table in same database by following the steps mentioned in the below link: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/NVARCHAR2. Even then its storing inverted question mark. I am using the dbvisualizer to create, insert modify oracle tables.

Comment: i upgraded DB to AL32UTF8, its working fine now. thanks

Comment: Well, if it didn't work, then you didn't use an `NVARCHAR` field. It's as simple as that. But using UTF8 as database character set is the fool-proof and maybe better solution.